# Python / Pandas UPSERT equivalent?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read and combine a bunch of excel reports (using a forloop) together into one final dataframe. Each file is for a different month and contains date, quote number, and a count of quotes (for columns XYZ). What I'm finding however is that quote numbers are duplicated across the excel files, with the same date, but different quote values.

For example, below I have two dataframes (or excel reports for September and October). I want to combine these together, but only keep the quote number "111" from the "October" report, as is more recent and contain an additional quote for the "X" column.

Assuming I have my excel reports named with the month / year, is there an easy way to do this? I'm thinking the logic is basically read in each file and append it to a master dataframe. If the file contains a quote number and date the same found in the master file, then replace the existing "XYZ" values for that quote number with the newer file's XYZ values for the quote number. Hopefully that all makes sense. I was thinking I could run another inner forloop, but I'm sure there must be a better / more efficient way of doing this. Many thanks!!

```
df_september = pd.DataFrame({'Quote number': [111, 222, 333], "Quote Date": ['2021-09-08', '2021-09-08', '2021-09-08'],
                   'X': [2, 1, 3], 'Y': [2, 2, 0], 'Z': [4, 2, 5]})

df_october = pd.DataFrame({'Quote number': [111, 444, 555], "Quote Date": ['2021-09-08', '2021-09-11', '2021-09-11'],
                   'X': [3, 5, 5], 'Y': [2, 2, 0], 'Z': [4, 2, 5]})
```

Comment: you probably need `combine_first`. Kindly add the expected output dataframe

Comment: I like the idea of a master df that you concat to. If you read in the months in reverse chronological order (i.e. October then September) you can ignore all quotes in the new_month that are already present in the master

Answer (score 2):

```
df_september.append(df_october).drop_duplicates('Quote number', keep='last')
```